# Python - generate the time difference

Tags: python

I am trying to generate a report for the usage statistics.Below is the sample data that i have in in an array and this is fetched from Mysql table.How to implement a logic saying that if the user is idle for more than 30 minutes he has not used the system else calculate the time mean time of the usage.

```
timestamp=[]
for i in timestamp:
   print i 

        2010-04-20 10:07:30
        2010-04-20 10:07:38
        2010-04-20 10:07:52
        2010-04-20 10:08:22
        2010-04-20 10:08:22
        2010-04-20 10:09:46
        2010-04-20 10:10:37
        2010-04-20 10:10:58
        2010-04-20 10:11:50
        2010-04-20 10:12:13
        2010-04-20 10:12:13
        2010-04-20 10:25:38
        2010-04-20 10:26:01
        2010-04-20 10:26:01
        2010-04-20 10:26:06
        2010-04-20 10:26:29
        2010-04-20 10:26:29
        2010-04-20 10:26:35
        2010-04-20 10:27:21
        2010-04-20 01:32:46
        2010-04-20 01:32:47
        2010-04-20 01:32:57
        2010-04-20 01:32:59
        2010-04-20 01:33:03
        2010-04-20 01:33:03
        2010-04-20 01:33:05
        2010-04-20 01:33:11
        2010-04-20 01:33:15
        2010-04-20 01:34:49
        2010-04-20 01:34:55
        2010-04-20 01:35:02
        2010-04-20 01:35:17
        2010-04-20 01:35:20
        2010-04-20 01:36:49
        2010-04-20 01:36:52
        2010-04-20 01:36:52
        2010-04-20 01:37:11
        2010-04-20 01:37:15
        2010-04-20 01:37:17
        2010-04-20 01:50:11
        2010-04-20 01:50:15
        2010-04-20 01:50:18
        2010-04-20 01:50:20
        2010-04-20 01:50:33
        2010-04-20 01:50:36
        2010-04-20 01:51:56
```

Comment: What exactly does this list of timestamps represent? Times they logged in to your system? Times they logged out? Both? Seeing as some of these times are only minutes apart, could it be the last time they performed a certain action with the system?

Comment: @WiseGuyEh :Logged in yes,Log out may be in which case there is a link array which has the log out entry link else not logged out just had closed the browser or not accessing the UI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you want.  It goes through the list calculating the difference between each entry and the previous one.  If the difference is bigger than or equal 30 minutes it ignores it. If it is less than 30 minutes it adds it to the total usage for that user.  (I'm assuming all the timestamps are for the same user.)

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

# Convert the timestamps to datetime objects
usetimes = sorted(datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for d in timestamp)

# Set the idle time to compare with later
idletime = timedelta(minutes = 30)

# Start the running total with a timedelta of 0
usage = timedelta()
last = usetimes[0]

for d in usetimes[1:]:
    delta = d - last
    if delta < idletime:
        usage += delta
    last = d

print "total usage:",usage
```

If you want to use `sum()` and `zip()` you can cut down the lines of code, but I'm not sure if it's as readable:

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
usetimes = sorted(datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for d in timestamp)
idletime = timedelta(minutes = 30)
usage = sum((x - y for x,y in zip(usetimes[1:],usetimes[:-1]) if x - y < idletime),timedelta())
print "total usage:", usage
```

In this case, if the list of timestamps is very long you could consider using `izip` from `itertools` instead of `zip`.

Comment: I would expect you to know better than to pass a list comprehension to `sorted`: it wastes memory _and_ two characters.

Comment: @aaronasterling Not sure how it "saves characters" since you would have to do `usetimes = [...]; usetimes.sort()`.  I think using `sorted` in this case is more readable.

Comment: @Dave, I meant it should be `sorted(datetime.strptime(...) for d in timestamp)` You don't actually have to construct the list just to throw it away after creating a copy of it.

Comment: Although it occurs to me that python will have to construct it anyways to sort it but the brackets look weird there at the very least. +1 anyways though.

Comment: @aaronasterling I see what you mean now, I've removed the brackets.  I think I left them on because when I first tested the code I didn't realise the timestamps weren't sorted and got a use time of -1½ days and so just put the `sorted()` in to fix that without removing the unnecessary brackets.  But I think you're right, Python will need to construct the whole list before sorting it.  But thanks for pointing out the brackets; I like my code to be pretty.  :-)

Comment: @aaronsterling - It appears you've prompted a question :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154571/sorted-using-generator-expressions-rather-than-lists

Comment: @Dave Webb. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154571/sorted-using-generator-expressions-rather-than-lists/4154734#4154734) to that question. Looks like I was right to begin with.

Comment: @aaronsterling - Not sure - `timeit` has the list comprehension running quicker than the generator.  I've checked in this case as well as the examples I posted in that question and the generator is slower here too, but not by all that much.  Most of the work is in the `strptime()` I think so the benefits of list comprehension or generator aren't that big.

Comment: Although to be clear I passed the list comprehension to `sorted()` by mistake not because I thought it was faster.  I'd have used the generator too if I had thought about it.