# sorted() using generator expressions rather than lists

Tags: python, optimization

After seeing the discussion here: [Python - generate the time difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154116/python-generate-the-time-difference/4154298#4154298) I got curious. I also initially thought that a generator is faster than a list, but when it comes to sorted() I don't know. Is there any benefit to sending a generator expression to sorted() rather than a list? Does the generator expression end up being made into a list inside sorted() before sorting anyway?

EDIT: It grieves me to only be able to accept one answer, as I feel a lot of responses have helped to clarify the issue. Thanks again to everyone.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The first thing `sorted()` does is to convert the data to a list.  Basically the first line (after argument validation) of the implementation is

```
newlist = PySequence_List(seq);
```

See also [the full source code version 2.7](http://svn.python.org/view/python/tags/r27/Python/bltinmodule.c?view=markup) and [version 3.1.2](http://svn.python.org/view/python/tags/r312/Python/bltinmodule.c?view=markup).

**Edit**: As pointed out in the [answer by aaronasterling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154571/sorted-using-generator-expressions-rather-than-lists/4155652#4155652), the variable `newlist` is, well, a *new* list.  If the parameter is already a list, it is copied.  So a generator expression really has the advantage of using less memory.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. Do you think there would be any advantage to performing some work during the first pass of the generator? I know this would be relatively inconsequential overall, but it seems like it might be slightly more efficient.

Comment: I presume they use Quicksort. It does not seem to be possible to do "some work" during the first pass -- it would involve swapping elements with the element at the end of the list, which is not yet known.

Comment: From what I've read about Python sorting, they do a lot of optimizations and do not just fall back to Quicksort. When transferring the values from the generator expression, you could theoretically do some comparisons with the values you have already placed onto your list.

Comment: @Sven They use TimSort which is an adaptive merge sort.

Comment: @aaronsterling: That's interesting!  Just read Tim Peters` description of in in [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort).  "It has supernatural performance on many kinds of partially ordered arrays" -- brilliant!

Comment: Well, I actually don't want to dive into this algorithm to decide if there is any potential for optimisation.  It is probably marginal.

Comment: I fully embrace its marginality. I just wanted to know what the trade offs were.

Comment: @Sven see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154571/sorted-using-generator-expressions-rather-than-lists/4154734#4154734). There's a difference after all.

Answer (score 19):

The easiest way to see which is faster is to use [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) and it tells me that it's faster to pass a list rather than a generator:

```
>>> import random
>>> randomlist = range(1000)
>>> random.shuffle(randomlist)
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit("sorted(x for x in randomlist)",setup = "from __main__ import randomlist",number = 10000)
4.944492386602178
>>> timeit.timeit("sorted([x for x in randomlist])",setup = "from __main__ import randomlist",number = 10000)
4.635165083830486
```

And:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("sorted(x for x in xrange(1000,1,-1))",number = 10000)
1.411807087213674
>>> timeit.timeit("sorted([x for x in xrange(1000,1,-1)])",number = 10000)
1.0734657617099401
```

I think this is because when `sorted()` converts the incoming value to a list it can do this more quickly for something that is already a list than for a generator.  [The source code seems to confirm this](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#-2BKs-LW4I0/trunk/python/src/Objects/listobject.c&q=_PyList_Extend&l=798) (but this is from reading the comments rather than fully understanding everything that is going on).

Comment: one point that has always been unclear to me is: how good is python exactly in detecting throw-away values and other, more trickier situations? it does detect some cases, so when you say `print( id( [42,] ) ); print( id( [42,] ) );` you regularly get reported the same id. python guarantees that when you compare the two list instances, they will have differing ids, but since that cannot happen here, python does it more efficiently and re-uses the memory. for this reason, it would be fairer to make sure the list is not a throw-away value, since then sorted cannot avoid copying it.

Answer (score 15):

There's no way to sort a sequence without knowing all the elements of the sequence, so any generator passed to `sorted()` is exhausted.

Comment: This makes sense. I'm also curious to know what sorted() does when it receives a generator. Does it immediately convert it to a list before performing the sort, or does the first pass of the sort algorithm over the generator do any work toward the actual sort.

Comment: look into "online sorting" like "stable sorting" but it sorts as you get elements, aka sorting w/o knowing all the elements of the sequence

Answer (score 12):

There's a huge benefit. Because sorted doesn't affect the passed in sequence, it has to make a copy of it. If it's making a list from the generator expression, then only one list gets made. If a list comprehension is passed in, then first, that gets built and then `sorted` makes a copy of it to sort.

This is reflected in the line

```
newlist = PySequence_List(seq);
```

quoted in [Sven Marnach's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154571/sorted-using-generator-expressions-rather-than-lists/4154734#4154734). Essentially, this will unconditionally make a copy of whatever sequence is passed to it.

Comment: You are right :)  But also note the timings by Dave Webb.  I will update my answer.

Comment: Good point, but what doesn't the implementation check whether the input iterable is a list, and if it is, then not make a copy?

Comment: @Chris_Rands *Because sorted doesn't affect the passed in sequence, it has to make a copy of it.*

Answer (score 9):

Python uses Timsort. Timsort needs to know the total number of elements up front, to compute the minrun parameter. Thus, as Sven reports, the first thing that sorted does when given a generator is to turn it into a list.

That said, it would be possible to write an incremental version of Timsort, which consumed values from the generator more slowly - you'd just have to fix minrun before starting, and accept the pain of having some unbalanced merges at the end. Timsort works in two phases. The first phase involves a pass through the whole array, identifying runs and doing insertion sort to make runs where the data is unordered. Both run-finding and insertion sort are inherently incremental. The second phase involves a merge of the sorted runs; that would happen exactly as now.

I don't think there would be a lot of point in this, though. Perhaps it would make memory management easier, because rather than having to read from the generator into a constantly-growing array (as i baselessly assume the current implementation does), you could read each run into a small buffer, then only allocate a final-sized buffer once, at the end. However, this would involve having 2N slots of array in memory at once, whereas a growing array can be done with 1.5N if it doubles when it grows. So, probably not a good idea.

Comment: Nice discussion about the pros and cons of handling the generator in sorted(). Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> I also initially thought that a list
>   comprehension is faster than a list

What do you mean faster than a list? Do you mean faster than an explicit `for`? For that I will say it depends: The list comprehension is more like a syntactic sugar, but it's very handy when it comes to simple loop.

> but when it comes to sorted() I don't
>   know. Is there any benefit to sending
>   a generator expression to sorted()
>   rather than a list?

The main difference between List comprehensions and Generator expressions is that the Generator expressions avoid the overhead of generating the entire list at once. Instead, they return a generator object which can be iterated one by one, so the Generator expressions are more likely used to save memory usage.

But you have to understand one thing in Python: It's very hard to tell if one way is faster (optimistic) than another way just by looking at it, and if you want to do that you should use [timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) for benchmarking (and benchmarking is more complex than just running one timeit on a single machine).

Read [this](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips) for more info about some optimization techniques.

Comment: In this case, I'm asking about the specific behavior of sorted(). I wouldn't go too far down the path of arguing about the syntax of list comprehensions and generators. EDIT: I also care about the question of if there is any theoretical advantage to processing the generator as you iterate over it.

Comment: @Brent Newey : i think you have already the answer about using sorted with generator expression from Sven Marnach, and for __there is any theoretical advantage to processing the generator as you iterate over it__ like i said in my answer it mostly for saving memory usage, think of a generator like this when you pass a genexpr to a loop the loop will ask every time give me the next item and each time the genexpr will generate this item for it like Just In Time (JIT) generation , hope my explanation was good :)

Answer (score 3):

I should just add to Dave Webb's timing answer [I put in what may be an anonymous edit], that when you access an optimized generator **directly**, it **may be** much faster; much of the overhead may be the code's creation of a list or generator of its own:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("sorted(xrange(1000, 1, -1))", number=10000)
0.34192609786987305
>>> timeit.timeit("sorted(range(1000, 1, -1))", number=10000)
0.4096639156341553
>>> timeit.timeit("sorted([el for el in xrange(1000, 1, -1)])", number=10000)
0.6886589527130127
>>> timeit.timeit("sorted(el for el in xrange(1000, 1, -1))", number=10000)
0.9492318630218506
```

Answer (score 1):

If performance is important why not process the data as it is yielded by the generator, and apply the ordering over results of the iterations? Of course this could be used only if there is no causal conditioning between iterations (i.e. the data of sorted iteration #[i] is not needed to do any calculation for sorted iteration #[i + 1]).
What I am trying to say in this case is that sorting a set of potentially larger structures yielded by the generator might be adding a lot of unnecessary complexity to an ordering which might take place posterior to processing all elements.