# Sort list elements based on two dictionaries

Tags: python, list, sorting

I was trying to sort the following list :

```
L = ['Z3', 'X3','V3','M0' ..., 'F2']
```

Based on the rules, I defined in the 2 following dictionaries:

```
dicMonths = {'F':1,'G':2,'H':3,'J':4,'K':5,'M':6,'N':7,'Q':8,'U':9,'V':10,'X':11,'Z':12}
dicYears = {'2':2022, '1':2021, '0':2020, '9':2019, '8':2018, '7':2017, '6':2016, '5':2015, '4':2014, '3':2013}
```

I applied the following code, but it doesn't work :

```
aa = [(elt[0], elt[1]) for elt in L]
sorted(aa, key= lambda x,y : (dicMonths[x], dicYears[y]))
```

It gives me the following error :

> TypeError: () missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

I want it to give me the sorted list as bellow :

```
['F3', 'G3', 'H3', 'J3', 'K3', 'M3', 'N3', 'Q3', 'U3', 'V3', 'X3', 'Z3', 'F4', ...]
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "it doesn't work".

Comment: I mean It doesn't sort the list

Comment: dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233476/sort-a-list-by-multiple-attributes

Comment: `key= lambda xy : (dicMonths[xy[0]], dicYears[xy[1]])`

Comment: You are missing the key `3` in `dicYears`. Please include reproducible code in your question not pseudo code (with '...') and your expected output.

Comment: Use one of these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892989/what-is-the-good-python3-equivalent-for-auto-tuple-unpacking-in-lambda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion from @flakes is very elegant, but probably does not produce the required output, because it gives month precedence over years.
However, according to the desired output mentioned in the question, years should have precedence over months - e.g. 'Z3' < 'F4'.

That can be achieved with a slight adaption:

```
sorted(L, key=lambda l: (dicYears[l[1]], dicMonths[l[0]]))
```

Comment: yes, you're right I recognized it when he posted the suggestion but forgot to mention it in the comment, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You provided an incompatible function for the `key` argument. `key` takes a function that accepts one argument and returns another. If you want this to work, you need to access the tuple argument as a single value.

Also, you don't need to split `L` as a separate step. Try this:

```
sorted(L, key=lambda l: (dicMonths[l[0]], dicYears[l[1]]))
```

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion works well.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny but I think you can upvote it