# Sorting Counter collection in python with secondary term (tie breaker)

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, counter

I have a `Counter` in `Python 3.3.x` which I want to sort.
I know I can use `.most_common(x)` but I want the keys to be sorted alphabetically in case of same value.
Is there a way I can do this ? Setting this kind of a 'tie breaker' ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is actually a dictionary and they rely on hashing technique, so we really cannot access them by order. Since accessing by order is not possible, sorting a dictionary is out of question. But you can convert that to a list of tuples which correspond to key and value, and then sort that. For example,

```
print(Counter('abracadabra').most_common())
# [('a', 5), ('r', 2), ('b', 2), ('c', 1), ('d', 1)]
print(sorted(Counter('abracadabra').most_common(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])))
# [('a', 5), ('b', 2), ('r', 2), ('c', 1), ('d', 1)]
```

We make the `sorted` sort the `(key, value)` data given by `most_common`. We want to make sure that the items have to be sorted descending by their `value` and in ascending by the `key`. So, we use a little trick here. `sorted` will call the function we pass as the value for `key` parameter, for each of the elements in the sequence to be sorted. The value returned by that function will be used to represent that particular element during comparison with other elements. In our case, the `key` function goes like this

```
lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])
```

Here, `x` will get all elements eventually and it swaps the position of first and second elements and negates the actual count part. Since, the `sorted`, by default, sorts the data in ascending order, we make the biggest number the smallest and vice-versa. For example,

```
[2, 3, 1]
```

If you want to sort them in ascending order, the `sorted` will keep the smallest element at the beginning and the next smallest in the second position and so on, till it reaches the largest element. In our case, it becomes `[1, 2, 3]`. To sort the elements in the descending order, we make their negated values represent the actual numbers.

```
sorted([2, 3, 1], key=lambda x: -x)
```

Now, when `sorted` picks `2`, it calls the `key` function to get the value to be used and it will return `-2` and the same way, `1` will be `-1`, `3` will be `-3`. It will be placing the element with the smallest at the beginning. Since we got `-3` for 3, 3 will be at the beginning, `2` will be next to it and 1 will be after it. So the result becomes `[3, 2, 1]`.

We apply the same technique, to sort based on two items in an element. We first sort based on the count values by descending and if they match sort based on the key, ascending.

Comment: You might as well use `items()` rather than `most_common()`: `sorted(Counter('abracadabra').items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))`. The only difference between the two methods is that `most_common()` returns the items in a different order, but that makes no difference since you have to re-sort the data anyway.

Comment: It's hard to compare `most_common` & `items` here. Since `Python` uses `timsort`, a partially ordered collection returned by `most_common` may sort faster. Also, `sorted` performs marginally better on [`lists` than `generators`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4155903/7102572) for some reason (the `dict_items` returned by items is effectively a generator). I suspect that copying a list to another list invokes `memcpy` under the hood whereas copying a generator to a list involves all the machinery of python iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of sorting by several options (and different ordering) in case of tiebreaks can be solved using sorted() and the lambda function applied to the 'keys' parameter.

```
result=sorted(result,key=lambda x: (-x[2],x[0],x[1]))
```

The `'-'`ve sign for `x[2]` implies that sorting should be done first by the *descending* order of the 3rd element of 'result'. `x[0], x[1]` further indicates that ties should be broken by the *ascending* order of `x[0]` and `x[1]` *in that exact order*. Also refer [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579202/breaking-ties-in-python-sort?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22046077)

Comment: @NelsonGon please check for the quality of new edit.