# Breaking ties in Python sort

Tags: python, sorting

I have a `list` of `tuple`s, each tuple contains two integers. I need to sort the the list (in reverse order) according to the difference of the integers in each tuple, but break ties with the larger first integer.

**Example**

For `[(5, 6), (4, 1), (6, 7)]`, we should get `[(4, 1), (6, 7), (5, 6)]`.

**My way**

I have already solved it by making a `dictionary` that contains the difference as the `key` and the tuple as the `value`. But the whole thing is a bit clumsy.

What is a better way?

Comment: should `6,7` come first or `5,6`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham `6, 7` since `6 > 5`.

Comment: why is the output in the answer `(5, 4), (6, 7)` then?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: the OP changed the sample, I am in the process of updating my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I see, that makes sense considering the question includes "break ties with the larger first integer".

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I interpreted that as *between two tuples, if the calculated difference is tied, break the tie based on the first value of the two tuples*. In a reverse sort, that means 6 is sorted before 5, 6 being the largest.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use a `key` function to `sorted()` and return a tuple; values will be sorted lexicographically:

```
sorted(yourlst, key=lambda t: (abs(t[0] - t[1])), t[0]), reverse=True)
```

I'm using `abs()` here to calculate a difference, regardless of which of the two integers is larger.

For your sample input, the key produces `(1, 5)`, `(3, 4)` and `(1, 6)`; in reverse order that puts `(1, 6)` (for the `(6, 7)` tuple) before `(1, 5)` (corresponding with `(5, 6)`).

Demo:

```
>>> yourlst = [(5, 6), (4, 1), (6, 7)]
>>> sorted(yourlst, key=lambda t: (abs(t[0] - t[1]), t[0]), reverse=True)
[(4, 1), (6, 7), (5, 6)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Given this `list=[('a','b',3),('d','e',3),('e','f',5)]`, if you'd like to sort by the number in descending order, but break ties (when counts are equal like with the '3' on this example) using ascending alphabetical order of the first element and then the second element repectively, the following code works:

```
sorted(list,key=lambda x: (-x[2],x[0],x[1]))
```

Here the '-' sign on the x[2] indicates it needs to be sorted in the descending order. 
The output will be: `[('e', 'f', 5), ('a', 'b', 3), ('d', 'e', 3)]`