# How to sort generator type in python

Tags: python, sorting, generator

My code has below lines

```
get_alarm_list = conn.query_alarms(query.filter_expr,
                                   query.orderb) 
print "type is:", type(get_alarm_list)
for alarm in get_alarm_list:
    if alarm.severity == 'critical':
        alarm.severity = 2
    elif alarm.severity == 'moderate':
        alarm.severity = 1
    else:
        alarm.severity = 0

alarm_list = sorted(get_alarm_list),
                    key=lambda a: a.severity,
                    reverse=True)
return [alarms.Alarm.from_db_model(alarm)
        for alarm in alarm_list]
```

Output:

```
type is <type 'generator'>
```

The objects in the list are:

```
for alarm in get_alarm_list:
     print alarm

Output:
<aodh.storage.models.Alarm object at 0x7fa4c0cb1c50>
<aodh.storage.models.Alarm object at 0x7fa4c0cb17d0>
<aodh.storage.models.Alarm object at 0x7fa4c0d86f10>
<aodh.storage.models.Alarm object at 0x7fa4ca372110>
<aodh.storage.models.Alarm object at 0x7fa4ca372190>
<aodh.storage.models.Alarm object at 0x7fa4c0c55d90>
```

And each alarm consists of the below data

```
 {'alarm_actions': [u'log://'], 'ok_actions': [], 'description': u'instance running hot', 'state': u'insufficient data', 'fields': ['alarm_actions', 'ok_actions', 'severity', 'timestamp', 'description', 'time_constraints', 'enabled', 'state_timestamp', 'rule', 'alarm_id', 'state', 'insufficient_data_actions', 'repeat_actions', 'user_id', 'project_id', 'type', 'name'], 'repeat_actions': False, 'enabled': True, 'state_timestamp': datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 27, 6, 41, 5, 987428), 'rule': {u'meter_name': u'cpu_util', u'evaluation_periods': 3, u'period': 600, u'statistic': u'avg', u'threshold': 70.0, u'query': [], u'comparison_operator': u'gt', u'exclude_outliers': False}, 'name': u'ddd', 'alarm_id': u'f5045ed5-5c53-4a6e-be53-23d3368f40c6', 'time_constraints': [], 'insufficient_data_actions': [], 'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 27, 6, 41, 5, 987428), 'user_id': u'9a65b258b5a24e74ac5feae2f6c54229', 'project_id': u'28d1c27e782c4448bf53da00f49d3e1b', 'type': u'threshold', 'severity': 2}
```

How can i iterate over the generator?

```
alarm_list = sorted(get_alarm_list,
                    key=lambda a: a.severity,
                    reverse=True)
```

But here `alarm_list` is empty. How can i use sort function on generator `get_alarm_list`

Comment: `sorted` works on generators. It will return a sorted list. Can you post enough code to reproduce your problem?

Comment: @khelwood I've edited my question and posted more code as your suggestion.

Comment: in version 2 you can use `for index, value in enumerate(get_alarm_list)` and update `get_alarm_list` as `get_alarm_list[index]`, so you won't need to create separe list...

Comment: The problem is that you are first iterating over `get_alarm_list`, thus consuming that generator, and the following call to `sorted(get_alarm_list)` results in an empty list because `get_alarm_list` doesn't have anymore elements.

Answer (score 6):

The problem in your code is that you are trying to sort exhausted generator ( you sorting after `for` loop thought generator). You can sort result produced by generator object, so the option for you is to exhaust generator into variable in other words to create new list based on `get_alarm_list` as `list(generator)` and then iterate and sort it with simple [sorted](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted) function or `list.sort` method:

```
get_alarm_list = conn.query_alarms(query.filter_expr, query.orderb) 
sorted_alarm_list = sorted(list(get_alarm_list),
                               key=lambda a: a.severity,
                               reverse=True)
for alarm in sorted_alarm_list:
    print alarm
```

**Note 1**: After execution of `list(get_alarm_list)` -  `get_alarm_list` generator became empty. And the only item which store result of `conn.query_alarms` is the `sorted_get_alarm_list`. You can read more about generators on [Generators Python Wiki](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=python+generator) and [Understanding Generators in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python)

**Note 2**: Actually you can pass generator object to `sorted` and you will get same list as passing `list(generator)`, however `sorted` works faster if you pass a list to it ( see more on SO answer [sorted() using Generator Expressions Rather Than Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154571/sorted-using-generator-expressions-rather-than-lists)).

Comment: Basically what i have tried in my code is something like `for alarm in get_alarm_list:    if alarm.severity == 2, alarm_list.append(alarm)` .Here i am appendind a list `alarm_list` after modifying the contents ob object. Is it correct?

Comment: I tried `list(get_alarm_list)` as per your suggestion. But its empty. `print list(get_alarm_list)` . output is `[]`

Comment: yes, because  generator is empty after first execution of list(get_alarm_list).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I have used a list, where i append alarm objects to it after modifying severity. And then i pass this list to sorted method. Do you think it is ok to do so?

Comment: you can sort this list in place with `list.sort()` method and do not create new one based on previous :) https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Comment: My code now is as in VERSION 2 in the question. Is it right to do so?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114328/discussion-between-sanjana-and-andriy-ivaneyko).

Comment: Your notes get to the right answer, but I think you should really change up your first sentence. It's flatly false to say you can't sort a generator.

Comment: @Blckknght agree, since sorted accept generator to sort ... but it still simply converted to list as first step of sorted...

Comment: sorting with `a.severity` which is a string like "critical" and "moderate" is unlikely to produce the required result. And the real problem is the generator is exhausted in the first `for` loop. Consider making the changes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're running into is that you're consuming the whole generator in your `for` loop when you modify the `severity` attributes of your objects. That means there's nothing left to iterate on when you call `sorted`, since generators are good for one use only.

You can fix this by getting rid of the first loop, and putting the severity-transforming logic into the `key` lambda function:

```
alarms_gen = conn.query_alarms(query.filter_expr, query.orderb) 
alarms_list = sorted(alarms_gen,
                     key=lambda x: {'critical': -2, 'moderate': -1}.get(x.severity, 0))
```

Note that I've renamed your `get_alarms_list` variable to be less misleading (it's not a list). I've also made it so that `reverse=True` is not needed in the sorted call by mapping the higher priorities to negative key values.

Comment: very concise and works perfectly. This way the object's severity value is preserved and not converted to an integer.  +1

Comment: Rather than using the easy-to-miss and confusing `-2` and `-1`, why not use `reverse=True`?

Comment: @NicHartley: That could work. You could also use any other values that are ordered the way you need, so you could do `{'critical': 0, 'moderate': 1}.get(x.severity, 2)`