# Python: Sort list of lists numerically

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have a list of `x`,`y` coordinates that I need to sort based on the `x` coordinate, then `y` coordinate when `x` is the same and eliminate duplicates of the same coordinates. For example, if the list is:

```
[[450.0, 486.6], [500.0, 400.0], [450.0, 313.3], [350.0, 313.3], [300.0, 400.0], 
 [349.9, 486.6], [450.0, 313.3]]
```

I would need to rearrange it to:

```
[[300.0, 400.0], [349.9, 486.6], [350.0, 313.3], [450.0, 313.3], [450.0, 486.6],
 [500.0, 400.0]]
```

(with one duplicate of `[450.0, 313.3]` removed)

Answer (score 6):

That is the normal sort order for a list of lists, anyway.  De-dupe it with a dict.

```
>>> L = [[450.0, 486.6], [500.0, 400.0], [450.0, 313.3], [350.0, 313.3], [300.0, 400.0], [349.9, 486.6], [450.0, 313.3]]
>>> sorted({tuple(x): x for x in L}.values())
[[300.0, 400.0],
 [349.9, 486.6],
 [350.0, 313.3],
 [450.0, 313.3],
 [450.0, 486.6],
 [500.0, 400.0]]
```

Comment: Is a dict more efficient than a set?

Comment: Probably.  Sets can't contain lists.

Comment: Of course, you cast to tuple first, then put in a set

Comment: @OlivierMelançon, which is exactly what I've done :)

Comment: But then you'd have to convert back to lists to get your output.

Comment: dict was faster on my platform (Python 3.7.0b4 on macOS).  Guess there's not much in it.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon Actually, take a look at my answer. With a more randomized input set than the one created by `jpp` (`L=100000*L`), dictionary approach is slightly faster than `jpp` solution.

Answer (score 2):

As we are sorting anyway we can dedupe with `groupby`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> [k for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(data))]                                                                 
[[300.0, 400.0], [349.9, 486.6], [350.0, 313.3], [450.0, 313.3], [450.0, 486.6], [500.0, 400.0]]
```

A few timings:

```
>>> import numpy as np # just to create a large example
>>> a = np.random.randint(0, 215, (10000, 2)).tolist()
>>> len([k for k, g in groupby(sorted(a))])
8977 # ~ 10% duplicates
>>> 
>>> timeit("[k for k, g in groupby(sorted(a))]", globals=globals(), number=1000)
6.1627248489967315
>>> timeit("sorted({tuple(x): x for x in a}.values())", globals=globals(), number=1000)
6.654527607999626
>>> timeit("sorted(unique(a, key=tuple))", globals=globals(), number=1000)
7.198703720991034
>>> timeit("np.unique(a, axis=0).tolist()", globals=globals(), number=1000)
8.848866895001265
```

Comment: Can you comment on the memory implications? I suspect [based on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154571/sorted-using-generator-expressions-rather-than-lists/4155652#4155652) that all but the `unique` will be making copies of the data. Of course, I may be wrong :).

Comment: `unique` needs to keep track of what's been seen already, meaning near the end of it being exhausted there will be the input list, `unique`s seen-that set and `sorted`s input list (`sorted` has to collect the entire input before it can start sorting) simultaneaously in memory. So there is no memory advantage for `unique`.

Answer (score 2):

What you want seems to be easily done with `numpy`'s `unique` function:

```
import numpy as np
u = np.unique(data, axis=0) # or np.unique(data, axis=0).tolist()
```

If you are really worried that the array is not sorted by columns, then run `np.lexsort()` in addition to the above:

```
u = u[np.lexsort((u[:,1], u[:,0]))]
```

#### Timings (non-random sample):

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: from toolz import unique

In [3]: data = [[450.0, 486.6], [500.0, 400.0], [450.0, 313.3],
   ...:  [350.0, 313.3], [300.0, 400.0], [349.9, 486.6], [450.0, 313.3]]
   ...:  

In [4]: L = 100000 * data

In [5]: npL = np.array(L)

In [6]: %timeit sorted(unique(L, key=tuple))
125 ms ± 1.72 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [7]: %timeit sorted({tuple(x): x for x in L}.values())
139 ms ± 3.41 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [8]: %timeit np.unique(L, axis=0)
732 ms ± 12.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [9]: %timeit np.unique(npL, axis=0)
584 ms ± 8.11 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# @user3483203 solution:

In [57]: %timeit lex(np.asarray(L))
227 ms ± 8.34 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [58]: %timeit lex(npL)
76.2 ms ± 410 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

#### Timings (more random sample):

When sample data are more random, the results are different:

```
In [29]: npL = np.random.randint(1,1000,(100000,2)) + np.random.choice(np.random.random(1000), (100000, 2))

In [30]: L = npL.tolist()

In [31]: %timeit sorted(unique(L, key=tuple))
143 ms ± 2.35 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [32]: %timeit sorted({tuple(x): x for x in L}.values())
134 ms ± 1.14 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [33]: %timeit np.unique(L, axis=0)
78.5 ms ± 1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [34]: %timeit np.unique(npL, axis=0)
54 ms ± 398 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# @Paul Panzer's solution:

In [36]: import itertools

In [37]: %timeit [k for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(L))]
123 ms ± 3.42 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# @user3483203 solution:

In [54]: %timeit lex(np.asarray(L))
60.1 ms ± 744 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [55]: %timeit lex(npL)
38.8 ms ± 728 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to preserve pairs. `np.unique` flattens by default.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Thanks! Locally, I have `axis=0` but not when posting... It's late

Answer (score 2):

We can do this quite fast using **`np.lexsort`** and some masking

```
def lex(arr):                 
    tmp =  arr[np.lexsort(arr.T),:]
    tmp = tmp[np.append([True],np.any(np.diff(tmp,axis=0),1))]
    return tmp[np.lexsort((tmp[:, 1], tmp[:, 0]), axis=0)]

L = np.array(L)
lex(L)

# Output:
[[300.  400. ]
 [349.9 486.6]
 [350.  313.3]
 [450.  313.3]
 [450.  486.6]
 [500.  400. ]]
```

### ***Performance***

#### `Functions`

```
def chrisz(arr):                 
    tmp =  arr[np.lexsort(arr.T),:]
    tmp = tmp[np.append([True],np.any(np.diff(tmp,axis=0),1))]
    return tmp[np.lexsort((tmp[:, 1], tmp[:, 0]), axis=0)]

def pp(data):
    return [k for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(data))]

def gazer(data):
    return np.unique(data, axis=0)

def wim(L):
    return sorted({tuple(x): x for x in L}.values())

def jpp(L):
    return sorted(unique(L, key=tuple))
```

### `Setup`

```
res = pd.DataFrame(
       index=['chrisz', 'pp', 'gazer', 'wim', 'jpp'],
       columns=[10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000, 50000, 100000],
       dtype=float
)

for f in res.index: 
    for c in res.columns:
        npL = np.random.randint(1,1000,(c,2)) + np.random.choice(np.random.random(1000), (c, 2))
        L = npL.tolist()
        stmt = '{}(npL)'.format(f) if f in {'chrisz', 'gazer'} else '{}(L)'.format(f)
        setp = 'from __main__ import L, npL, {}'.format(f)
        res.at[f, c] = timeit(stmt, setp, number=50)

ax = res.div(res.min()).T.plot(loglog=True) 
ax.set_xlabel("N"); 
ax.set_ylabel("time (relative)");

plt.show()
```

[image]

### `Validation`

```
npL = np.random.randint(1,1000,(100000,2)) + np.random.choice(np.random.random(1000), (100000, 2))    
L = npL.tolist()    
chrisz(npL).tolist() == pp(L) == gazer(npL).tolist() == wim(L) == jpp(L)
True
```

Comment: @AGNGazer should be fixed now, it actually got faster I believe.  I validated using `np.all(np.unique(npL, axis=0) == lex(npL))`

Comment: Just added your timings. Very fast!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using `sorted` and `toolz.unique`:

```
from toolz import unique

res = sorted(unique(L, key=tuple))

print(res)

[[300.0, 400.0], [349.9, 486.6], [350.0, 313.3],
 [450.0, 313.3], [450.0, 486.6], [500.0, 400.0]]
```

Note `toolz.unique` is also available via the standard library as the `itertools` `unique_everseen` [recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes). Tuple conversion is necessary as the algorithm uses hashing via `set` to check uniqueness.

Performance using `set` appears slightly better than `dict` here, but as always you should test with your data.

```
L = L*100000

%timeit sorted(unique(L, key=tuple))               # 223 ms
%timeit sorted({tuple(x): x for x in L}.values())  # 243 ms
```

I suspect this is because `unique` is lazy, and so you have less memory overhead since `sorted` isn't making a *copy* of the input data.

Comment: Sorry, but that's just plain incorrect. Sorted will consume the entire sequence before doing any comparisons, it requires an intermediary structure in memory all the same - it's irrelevant here whether unique iterates lazy or not.

Comment: @wim, Is that intermediary structure a `list`, or a `dict`? There's a cost attached to creating Python structures, e.g. try `sorted(range(10000))` vs `sorted(list(range(10000)))`, I know which I'd prefer.

Comment: @wim, The memory benefit is from the fact that if you feed a list (or other in-memory iterable), `sorted` will [make its own list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154571/sorted-using-generator-expressions-rather-than-lists/4155652#4155652) prior to sorting, i.e. if you feed a list it'll copy it. This copy is what I call an intermediary structure.

Comment: In my case, it's a `dict_values` view.  `unique` also necessarily needs to maintain some intermediary structures somehow (I assume it uses a set).  If you didn't notice it, that's because your testing was flawed: setting `L = L*100000` means the data contains virtually 100% dupes.