# Numpy remove duplicate column values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array as follows

```
array([[ 6,  5],
   [ 6,  9],
   [ 7,  5],
   [ 7,  9],
   [ 8, 10],
   [ 9, 10],
   [ 9, 11],
   [10, 10]])
```

I want to pick elements such that y coordinates are unique. If two y coordinates are same I want to pick element with lesser x coordinate.

Expected output

```
array([[ 6,  5],
   [ 6,  9],
   [ 8, 10],
   [ 9, 11]])
```

Explanation

pick `[6,5]` over `[7,5]`

pick `[8,10]` over `[9,10]` and `[10,10]`

pick `[9, 11]`

Thanks

Comment: Please post what you have tried already.

Comment: I did a naive looping. Played around with unique didn't get anywhere

Comment: Is the array always sorted on x-coordinate as given in the example?

Comment: @gaganso Not necessarily. I can sort them for convenience

Comment: Just sort before you use `unique`

Comment: @user3483203 unique just gives me unique rows or unique individual elements. I wanted unique column values and also get the whole row. I tried np.unique(d[:,1])

Comment: Yea, but you can boolean index based on the indices returned by unique

Comment: @user3483203 Thanks. I did not notice earlier that unique returns indices

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, sort by the first column:

```
a = a[a[:, 0].argsort()]
```

Returning unique indices using [**`np.unique`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with the **`return_index`** flag:

```
a[np.unique(a[:, 1], return_index=True)[1]]

array([[ 6,  5],
       [ 6,  9],
       [ 8, 10],
       [ 9, 11]])
```

Some timings:

```
a = np.random.randint(1, 10, 10000).reshape(-1, 2)

In [45]: %timeit rows_by_unique_y(a)
3.83 ms ± 137 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [46]: %timeit argsort_unique(a)
370 µs ± 8.26 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Yes, my approach uses an initial sort, but vectorized operations in numpy beat iteration in Python.

Comment: Sorting is asymptotically suboptimal for this problem. O(n log n) vs O(n)

Comment: Why don't you time both of our approaches, looping when using numpy is bad

Comment: +1, cheers. Yours indeed has a much lower constant! I often underestimate just how slow Python interpreters are.

Comment: @AlexReinking yea it's a counter-intuitive thing when working with numpy.  In answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50959180/python-sort-list-of-lists-numerically/50960136#50960136), I actually sort something twice when dropping duplicates and it still easily beats any vanilla python approach.

Comment: Playing with a few input array sizes, I can actually see the linear vs n-log-n scaling, but the crossing point is around 25 million rows

Answer (score 2):

If you are open to using another library, I would suggest using [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) for an efficient and compact solution

```
import numpy as np
import numpy_indexed as npi

a = np.array([[6, 5], [6, 9], [7, 5], [7, 9], [8, 10], [9, 10], [9, 11], [10, 10]])

column_to_groupby = 1
groups, reduced = npi.group_by(a[:,column_to_groupby]).min(a)
print(reduced)
```

It gives the following output

```
[[ 6  5]
 [ 6  9]
 [ 8 10]
 [ 9 11]]
```

Here is the timeit result

```
In [5]: a = np.random.randint(1, 10, 10000).reshape(-1, 2)

In [6]: %timeit npi.group_by(a[:,1]).min(a)
354 µs ± 2.29 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach loop through the array and make a note of the best values you've seen, then reconstruct the array at the end:

```
import numpy as np

def rows_by_unique_y(arr):
  best_for_y = defaultdict(lambda: float('inf'))
  for i, row in enumerate(arr):
    x,y = row[0], row[1]
    best_for_y[y] = min(x, best_for_y[y])
  return np.array([[x,y] for y, x in best_for_y.items()])

arr = np.array([[6,  5], [6,  9], [7,  5], [7,  9], [8, 10], [9, 10], [9, 11], [10, 10]])
print(rows_by_unique_y(arr))
```

No need to sort, just keep track of the minimums. This outputs:

```
[[ 6  5]
 [ 6  9]
 [ 8 10]
 [ 9 11]]
```

---

While this answer is asymptotically faster, [user3483203's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51236631/2137996) is much better in practice. This is because it calls out to optimized C code rather than staying inside of Python's surprisingly slow interpreter. However, if your arrays are *huge* (several gigabytes) then the O(n log n) behavior will start to lose to this.

At the same time, if your arrays are that large, you should probably be using a MapReduce framework like Spark instead. The algorithm I gave above is easily parallelized.

---

If you don't need the minimum `x` values, then the following one-liner using `np.unique` works:

```
arr[np.unique(arr[:,1], return_index=True)[1]]
```

but this returns

```
array([[ 6,  5],
       [ 6,  9],
       [10, 10],
       [ 9, 11]])
```

if you switch the `8` and the `10`.

Comment: Thank you Alex. I was trying to avoid looping. Tried using something np.unique(d[:,1]) and play around with it

Comment: It's going to be difficult to square the behavior of `np.unique` with your need to keep the minimum `x` value. If you find that you need to sort, I would thoroughly test that solution against this one, since sorting will make the algorithm O(n log n) while my code runs in amortized (for the hash table) O(n).

Comment: @user009122 - I added how you would use `np.unique` if you didn't have the x-value constraint

Comment: You are right about the complexity. My use case I was looking for a concise code and I am not too bothered about complexity