# Lazy sorted function, timsort

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, sorting

Having a list with N (large number) elements:

```
from random import randint

eles = [randint(0, 10) for i in range(3000000)]
```

I'm trying to implement the best way (performance/resources spent) this function below:

```
def mosty(lst):
    sort = sorted((v, k) for k, v in enumerate(lst))
    count, maxi, last_ele, idxs = 0, 0, None, []
    for ele, idx in sort:
        if(last_ele != ele):
            count = 1
            idxs = []
        idxs.append(idx)
        if(last_ele == ele):
            count += 1
            if(maxi < count):
                results = (ele, count, idxs)
                maxi = count
        last_ele = ele
    return results
```

This function returns the most common element, number of occurrences, and the indexes where it was found.

Here is the [benchmark](https://repl.it/@mf1985/IgnorantSolidClicks) with 300000 eles.

But I think I could improve, one of the reasons being python3 `sorted` function ([timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort)), if it returned a generator I didn't have to loop through the list twice right?

My questions are:

**Is there any way for this code to be optimized? How?**

**With a lazy sorting I sure it would be, am I right? How can I implement lazy timsort**

Comment: Try if you can use generators in this place.

Comment: What is that function trying to do exactly?

Comment: relevant https://stackoverflow.com/a/4154954/6260170

Comment: you can certainly improve your implementation, but I think the lazy sorting idea is not the right way to do so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did not do any benchmarks, but that should not perform that badly (even though it iterates twice over the list):

```
from collections import Counter
from random import randint

eles = [randint(0, 10) for i in range(30)]

counter = Counter(eles)
most_common_element, number_of_occurrences = counter.most_common(1)[0]
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(eles) if x == most_common_element]

print(most_common_element, number_of_occurrences, indices)
```

and the indices (the second iteration) can be found lazily in a generator expression:

```
indices = (i for i, x in enumerate(eles) if x == most_common_element)
```

---

if you need to care about multiple elements being the most common, this might work for you:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

eles = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]

counter = Counter(eles)
_key, group = next(groupby(counter.most_common(), key=itemgetter(1)))
most_common = dict(group)
indices = {key: [] for key in most_common}

for i, x in enumerate(eles):
   if x in indices:
        indices[x].append(i)

print(most_common)
print(indices)
```

you could of course still make the `indices` lazy the same way as above.

Comment: @Chris_Rands was not quite there yet... sorry. updated now.

Comment: you fail to handle joint top elements e.g. `eles = [1,1,2,2]`

Comment: that is correct. thanks for pointing out. that could be easily fixed though. not looking into that as long as i'm unsure the OP is interested in this variant...

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to use numpy, then you can do something like this:

```
arr = np.array(eles)
values, counts = np.unique(arr, return_counts=True)
ind = np.argmax(counts)
most_common_elem, its_count = values[ind], counts[ind]
indices = np.where(arr == most_common_elem)
```

HTH.